# Where do we find the sources in the tora for these places/actions

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, resurrection-of-the-dead

What is the mekor for the names of the Land of Israel: Eretz Yisroel and Eretz Hakodesh?

Comment: The term "Eretz Yisroel" appears numerous times in midrashim and throughout shas

Comment: Hi c Fisher, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Great question. However, this question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only. Please edit your question, since it might get deleted because of the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

The source for bodies rolling can be found in a couple of places:

Famously in the Gemara in [Kesubos 111a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וּלְרַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר, צַדִּיקִים שֶׁבְּחוּץ לָאָרֶץ אֵינָם חַיִּים?! אָמַר רַבִּי אִילְעָא: **עַל יְדֵי גִּלְגּוּל**. מַתְקֵיף לַהּ רַבִּי אַבָּא סַלָּא רַבָּא: גִּלְגּוּל לְצַדִּיקִים צַעַר הוּא! אָמַר אַבָּיֵי: מְחִילּוֹת נַעֲשׂוֹת לָהֶם בַּקַּרְקַע.
>
> The Gemara asks: And according to the opinion of Rabbi Elazar, will the righteous outside of Eretz Yisrael not come alive at the time of the resurrection of the dead? Rabbi Ile’a said: **They will be resurrected by means of rolling**, i.e., they will roll until they reach Eretz Yisrael, where they will be brought back to life. Rabbi Abba Salla Rava strongly objects to this: Rolling is an ordeal that entails suffering for the righteous. Abaye said: Tunnels are prepared for them in the ground, through which they pass to Eretz Yisrael. (Sefaria translation & notation)

and in the [Zohar 1:131](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.131a.7?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> תָּא חֲזֵי, הָא אִתְּמָר כָּל אִינוּן מֵתִין דִּבְאַרְעָא דְיִשְׂרָאֵל יְקוּמוּן בְּקַדְמִיתָא, בְּגִין דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא יִתְעַר עֲלַיְיהוּ וְיוֹקִים לוֹן, עֲלַיְיהוּ כְּתִיב יִחְיוּ מֵתֶיךָ, אִלֵּין אִינוּן דִּי בְאַרְעָא דְיִשְׂרָאֵל. נְבֵלָתִי יְקוּמוּן, אִלֵּין אִינוּן דִּבְגוֹ אַרְעָאן אָחֳרָנִין, דְּלָא כְּתִיב בְּהוּ תְּחִיָּיה אֶלָּא קִימָה. דְּהָא רוּחָא דְחַיֵּי לָא תִשְׁרֵי אֶלָּא בְּאַרְעָא קַדִּישָׁא דְיִשְׂרָאֵל, וּבְגִין כָּךְ כְּתִיב בְּהוּ יִחְיוּ מֵתֶיךָ, וְאִינוּן דִּלְבַר, **יִתְבְּרֵי גוּפָא דִלְהוֹן וִיקוּמוּן גּוּפָא בְּלָא רוּחָא. וּלְבָתַר יִתְגַּלְגְּלוּן תְּחוֹת עַפְרָא עַד דְּיִמְטוּן לְאֶרֶץ יִּשְׂרָאֵל, וְתַמָּן יְקַבְּלוּן נִשְׁמָתָא**, וְלָא בִּרְשׁוּ אָחֳרָא, בְּגִין דְּיִתְקַיְּימוּן בְּעַלְמָא כְּדְקָא חָזֵי.
>
> Come and behold, We have learned that all the dead in the land of Israel will be resurrected first, because the Holy One, blessed be He, will arouse them and revive them. Of them it is written, "The dead...shall live" ([Isaiah 26:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.26.19?lang=bi)) This verse refers to those buried in the land of Israel. "My dead body shall arise" refers to those buried in other countries, for whom the term "restoration" is used in place of "resurrection." This is because the spirit of life dwells only in the Holy Land of Israel. Therefore, "The dead man of your people shall live" refers only to those buried in the land Israel. **The bodies of those outside will be created, but they will be resurrected as a body with no spirit. Thereafter, they will roll under the soil of the land until they reach the land of Israel, where they will receive a soul.** They will not receive this soul under any other authority, so they will be well established in the world.